# How can I reset $PATH in OSX?

Tags: macos, path

When I run:

```
echo $PATH
```

I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

This is obviously completely messed up. So, how can I fix this or reset $PATH?

I'm running on El Capitan.

Comment: Other than the duplicate path entries make your PATH variable look messy, your PATH variable should work fine.

Comment: What is actually wrong with PATH? That you have too many Python framework declarations?

Comment: Oh, I guess nothing is wrong with it then...My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To find .bash_profile enter in Terminal.app:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
   ```
2. The .bash_profile should be in your home file folder.
3. Open this file with some editor, like textEdit and paste it there:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin   
   export PATH  
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"  
   PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:"$PATH"
   ```
4. Close and save it, then restart the console.
5. Tap it, to hide hidden files:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
   ```

Comment: What does the **int** in ".bash_profile will be **int**?" mean?

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The default shell on OSX is `bash`. So you can set your path in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using TextEdit, click <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> Open `user` folder and then click <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to see hidden files and select `.bash_profile`, then edit the file to update path as below:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
```

Save the file, and run the command `source .bash_profile` from terminal.